# Live Interface Builder update with @IBDesignable for custom NSSlider control

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, appkit

I have problems in getting my custom **NSSlider** control updated live within Xcode's Interface Builder.

I have implemented `@IBDesignable` and `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` as shown in many other posts and tutorials. My little test just removes the knob from the slider control.
Here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
import Cocoa


@IBDesignable
class ColorSlider2: NSSlider {
    override func setNeedsDisplay(_ invalidRect: NSRect) {
        super.setNeedsDisplay(invalidRect)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupView()
    }


    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    private func setupView() {
        if ((self.cell?.isKind(of: ColorSlider2Cell.self)) == false) {
            let cell = ColorSlider2Cell()
            self.cell = cell
        }
        self.alphaValue = 0.5
        self.floatValue = 0.4
    }
}



class ColorSlider2Cell: NSSliderCell {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect) {
        return
    }
}
```

The preview in Interface Builder is neither removing the knob nor updating the floatValue:
[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea why this is the case?

Comment: It seems that this behavior is caused by "not implemented yet"? May be subject to report to Apple.